# How the response header is set

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Why does the response header is set after a filenotfound exception.
Technically the headers are set only after getting the file.

```
try {
    //codes 
    File file = new File(zipDestinationPath);               
    response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
    response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));
    is = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

}  catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        //i am not setting header here commentedit.
        // response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode("Error", "UTF-8"));
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-15");
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println(("Invalid file path :" +zipDestinationPath).getBytes());
        out.write(("Invalid file path :" +zipDestinationPath).getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It appears this file is remote and is accessed via HTTP, can you confirm this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `File` does not throw a `FileNotFoundException`. The `FileNotFoundException` is only thrown when you create the `FileInputStream`, at which point you've already set the headers. Try rearranging it like

```
           File file = new File(zipDestinationPath);               
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
            response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
            response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));
```